# 160 ohm circuit with only 100 ohm resistors

Tags: resistors, parallel, series

Can anyone please show, or describe how to get 160 ohm resistance out of a circuit with only 100 ohm resistors, maxium of 5 resistors?

I know it is probably a combination of a series and parallel circuit but can't quite figure it out. Bit of a brain teaser I guess.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try to start with  $$300~\Omega$$ and work from there...

Comment: Think about a ladder...

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: It's an extra credit thing, find various values with only 5 - 100 ohm resisotrs, I've gotten them all except for the 160 ohm which is stumping me.

Comment: also start with 50 Ω

Comment: also a very simple [**very very inefficient**] way for solving more generic problems of this type could be done by recursion, where every time your code tries to form the equivalent resistance by making a parallel network of the only available resistance, i have managed to write one on the run 
https://trinket.io/library/trinkets/ed840c000e

For example building a total resistance of 101 ohm out of 100 ohm could be done by 100 ohm series with 100 parallel 100ohm of r total = 1 ! `(100 -- (100*//100//))`

Answer (score 1):

[image: Circuit]

Here's what I came up with. Trial and error should have gotten you to a similar point.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't that come out to 150? Could be the answer if the within 10% thing applies.